# Difference in program output in different environments

Tags: c, compiler-errors, backtracking

I am new to coding and I was trying my hands at backtracking with a sample problem to print all the subsets from a given set of number having sum of members equal to a given value.

I am facing a very weird problem with the code below which happens to work well and gives the desired output on online compilers like ideone.com but gives erroneous ouput on my system. Can I get an explanation as to why this is happening and the possible reasons ?

```
//works well on online compilers

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void printArray(int *a, int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%d ",a[i]);
    printf("\n");
    return;
}

void subsetSum(int *set, int *tuple, int setSize, int tupleSize, int current, int sum, int const target)
{
    if(sum==target)
    {
        printArray(tuple,tupleSize);
        subsetSum(set,tuple,setSize,tupleSize-1,current+1,sum-set[current],target);//call further for items excluding this one
    }
    else
    {
        int i;
        for(i=current;i<setSize;i++)
        {
            tuple[tupleSize]=set[i];    //add the ith node to tuple and move down for backtracking
            subsetSum(set,tuple,setSize,tupleSize+1,i+1,sum+set[i],target); ///after this backtrack to other possible nodes
        }
    }
    return;
}

void getSubsets(int *set, int size, int const target)
{
    int *tuple=(int*)malloc(size*sizeof(int));
    subsetSum(set,tuple,size,0,0,0,target);
    free(tuple);
    return;
}

int main(void)
{
    int weights[] = {10, 7, 5, 18, 12, 20, 15};
    int size = 7;
    getSubsets(weights, size, 32);
    return 0;
}
```

Expected output (as on ideone)

```
10 7 15 
7 5 20 
5 12 15 
12 20
```

Erroneous output on pc

```
10 7 15 
10 7 
10 

7 5 20 
5 12 15 
5 12 
5 

12 20
```

Comment: Were there any compiler warnings? Did you use a debugger to inspect your program's execution state? Did you know you don't have to explicitly `return;` at the end of a function returning `void`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are reading past the end of the `set[]` array (allocated as `tuple[]`) which results in undefined behaviour (UB).

1. Consider the first time in the for loop when `i=6` (`setsize-1`).
2. You then call:

   ```
   subsetSum(set,tuple,setSize,tupleSize+1, (setsize-1)+1, sum+set[i],target);
   ```
3. This means in the function call to `subsetSum()` that `current == setsize`.
4. Assuming that `sum==target` you print the array (fine) but then you do:

   ```
   subsetSum(set,tuple,setSize,tupleSize-1, setsize+1, sum-set[setsize],target);
   ```

   which overflows in the `set[setsize]` call.

Removing the recursive function call after `printArray()` removes the buffer overflow and thus the UB and things work fine. The reason it "worked" initially in one compiler/environment is simply due to the nature of a UB...sometimes it seems to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the ideone version seems to work, but in any case, I don't think you need this line in the first if-block:

```
subsetSum(set,tuple,setSize,tupleSize-1,current+1,sum-set[current],target);//call further for items excluding this one
```

The "backtracking" happens when each stack layer returns.

Comment: yeah I tried that and now it works fine both on my system as well as online compiler, sorry for that really stupid mistake, but that still doesn't account for the difference when the line was included, i.e. the output should have been same(equally wrong) on both right ??

Comment: @RandomPerson Yeah, you're right, I think they should be identical.  I've never used ideone (nor do I know anything about it), but this seems like some non-standard quirk that it must have.

Comment: I am looking for something like can two different compilers versions compile same program logic in totally different ways ? (So far I think not) Also i tried on 2-3 more online compilers it seems to be working everywhere :P